# When does the system go from Connected Standby state to Hibernate automatically?

Tags: hibernate, windows-8, windows-8.1, standby

I have Thinkpad tablet 2 Windows 8.0. I just want to know when does my machine automatically goes from Connected standby to hibernate.

*Is it time based? Meaning will it shift from Connected Standby to Hibernate when it reaches specific length of time?

*Is it batter level based? Meaning will it shift from Connected Standby to Hibernate when it reaches specific battery level?

Answer (score 0):

I hit your question while researching a similar topic - because I don't want my laptop to wake up in the Connected Standby while it's in my bag commuting to and from work.

I don't believe there is anything time-based. If you have hibernation enabled on the system (powercfg /h on), there is a setting that can be customized on the power plan to hibernate the system when the battery reaches low or critical state (as well as configure the percentages of battery charge that constitute the low/critical):

See image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFa6A.png (I don't have the reputation to post images)

You can also force the system to hibernate by issuing shutdown /h from administrative command prompt

Here's a relevant MSDN reference also:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn481218(v=vs.85).aspx

Alex

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the critical battery threshold is reached. The critical threshold and the action what happens when it is reached can be changed in the "Power Options" dialog:

[image]

To get to that dialog:

Search for "power" on the start screen and open "Edit power plan". Then click "Change advanced power settings".

Answer (score 0):

system can also transition to hibernate from inside connected standby under thermal stress. Bios usually has a setting for that under thermal management.